# MsDeploy stopped deploying a directory during CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have a project structure that looks roughly like this

```
Root
  MyProject.Web
     App
        js
        sass
        img
        other stuff..
     other stuff...
  other stuff...
```

For some reason, msdeploy has suddenly stopped copying over my `sass` directory. Some things I've known to check from experience:

- It *is* included in the csproj. This is done via a wildcard on the App directory `<Content Include="App\**\*" />`. I have used this on several projects and in fact it was working previously on *this* project.
- It *is* being listed during webdeploy's `CollectFilesFromContent` step.

And yet it is omitted during the `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy` step

I am launching this from CI by pointing `MsBuild` at `MyProject.Web.csproj` with the following parameters

```
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:Configuration=QA /p:MsDeployServiceUrl="https://${bamboo.deployServer}:8172/MsDeploy.axd";DeployIisAppPath="${bamboo.deploySite}";username="${bamboo.deployUser}";password="${bamboo.deployPassword}" /p:SolutionDir=${bamboo.build.working.directory}\ /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true
```

here is a truncated copy of my log that should demonstrate what I'm saying

```
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04    CollectFilesFromContent:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04      Gather all files from Project items @(Content). Adding:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04      
App\img\loading.gif;
<...snip...>
App\js\app.js;
App\js\directives\adminNavigation.js;
<...snip...>
App\js\screens\myTime\listView.html;
<...snip...>
App\sass\admin.css;
App\sass\admin.scss;
App\sass\home.css;
App\sass\home.scss;
App\sass\lib\_normalize.scss;
App\sass\login.css;
App\sass\login.scss;
<...snip...>
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04    CollectFilesFromIntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04      Gather all files from Project output (IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath). Adding:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04    CollectFilesFromReference:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04      Gather all files from Project items @(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths,ReferenceComWrappersToCopyLocal,ResolvedIsolatedComModules,_DeploymentLooseManifestFile,NativeReferenceFile).
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04    CollectFilesFromAllExtraReferenceFiles:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04      Gather all files from Project items @(AllExtraReferenceFiles). Adding:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04    CollectFilesFrom_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectory:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04      Gather all files from Project items @(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectoryAlways,_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectory). Adding:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04      bin\Version.txt
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04    CollectFilesFrom_binDeployableAssemblies:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:04      Gather all files from Project items @(_binDeployableAssemblies). Adding:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05    PipelineCollectFilesPhase:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Publish Pipeline Collect Files Phase
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05    PreTransformWebConfig:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Found The following for Config tranformation:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Web.config
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Creating directory "E:\CI_BUILD_DIRECTORY\obj\QA\TransformWebConfig\transformed\".
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Creating directory "E:\CI_BUILD_DIRECTORY\obj\QA\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Views\".
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying Web.config to obj\QA\TransformWebConfig\original\Web.config.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying E:\CI_BUILD_DIRECTORY\Web.QA.config to obj\QA\TransformWebConfig\assist\Web.config.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05    TransformWebConfigCore:
<...snip...>
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Transformation succeeded
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05    PostTransformWebConfig:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Transformed Web.config using E:\CI_BUILD_DIRECTORY\Web.QA.config into obj\QA\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05    PipelineTransformPhase:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Publish Pipeline Transform Phase
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05    PreAutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Creating directory "E:\CI_BUILD_DIRECTORY\obj\QA\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Views\".
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying Views\Web.config to obj\QA\CSAutoParameterize\original\Views\Web.config.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying obj\QA\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config to obj\QA\CSAutoParameterize\original\Web.config.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05    AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStringsCore:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Transforming Source File: E:\CI_BUILD_DIRECTORY\Views\Web.config
<...snip...>
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Transformation succeeded
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Transforming Source File: E:\CI_BUILD_DIRECTORY\obj\QA\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05        Applying Transform File: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<...snip...>
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Transformation succeeded
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05    PostAutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Auto ConnectionString Transformed Views\Web.config into obj\QA\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Views\Web.config.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Auto ConnectionString Transformed obj\QA\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config into obj\QA\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05    PipelineMsdeploySpecificTransformPhase:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Publish Pipeline Deploy phase Stage PipelineMsdeploySpecificTransformPhase
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05    CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Creating directory "obj\QA\Package\PackageTmp".
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      obj\QA\Package\PackageTmp.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying bin\MyProject.Web.dll to obj\QA\Package\PackageTmp\bin\MyProject.Web.dll.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying bin\MyProject.Web.pdb to obj\QA\Package\PackageTmp\bin\MyProject.Web.pdb.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying App\img\loading.gif to obj\QA\Package\PackageTmp\App\img\loading.gif.
<...snip...>
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying App\js\app.js to obj\QA\Package\PackageTmp\App\js\app.js.
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying App\js\directives\adminNavigation.js to obj\QA\Package\PackageTmp\App\js\directives\adminNavigation.js.
<...snip...>
build   12-Feb-2016 18:57:05      Copying App\js\screens\myTime\listView.html to obj\QA\Package\PackageTmp\App\js\screens\myTime\listView.html.
<...other files BUT NOT the sass directory...>
```

So this directory is gathered for deploy but then not actually deployed. I'm at a loss at how to even debug this further!

Comment: Are you sure these files have changed?  MSDeploy only deploys changed files by default.  You could also try deploying locally or to a different target to see if the same issue happens.

Comment: @chief7 its actually  deleting them on source but that's a fantastic idea. Deploying locally also does't deploy those files! I have no idea what that means but that shortens my feedback loop for playing with this significantly

Answer (score 0):

After a day of random guess-checking I've discovered that the issue seems to for some reason be the actual directory name `sass`. Renaming the directory to `css` fixed the issue!

This is obviously insane. Unless msdeploy has a hard-coded list of folders within it I can't imagine how this works. If anyone have any details please post an answer and I'll accept it.